# str_replace or preg_replace random number from string

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I have a url from where i am fetching value using GET method and i want to replace that value with the 4 digit random number in the string like

This is my main URL:
    http://localhost/ab/index.php?id=3345

These are the strings in my table (fetching from database):

```
http://anyurl/index.php?id=4876&abc=any
http://anyurl/index.php?id=8726&abc=any
http://anyurl/index.php?id=9026&abc=any
```

So whenever i open the main url the id's of the table should be replaced according to the main url

Comment: Do you want to replace string id with the id of main URL?

Comment: @AmitGupta the strings id should be replaced by main url id

Comment: ok fine why do you want to use str_replace or preg_replace instead of GET?

Comment: @AmitGupta the urls in the table are coming from database so whenever i open the main url the id of url coming from database should be changed according to the id of main url

Comment: Its not that much clear to me. Your main URL is also coming from database?

Comment: Can you share PHP code in which you are doing all this?

Comment: @AmitGupta no main url is of address bar

Comment: Then you can change the id of strings very easily. Where is the issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161570/discussion-between-amit-gupta-and-a-r).

Comment: Please check my answer. You can do with preg_replace like you want. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can get the id parameter using global GET variable

```
$id = $_GET["id"]
```

then you can change the urls in the table according to it

```
$url = "http://anyurl/index.php?id=".$id."&abc=any"
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: the url coming from the database are all different with different id's there is no same pattern except the id is of 4 digit

Comment: can you explain it with an example. I' m not clear about it

Comment: http://anyurl/index.php?id=9026&abc=any this can be any thing and i am fething this from database.. The main url is of address bar. SO the id of the main url from the address bar should replace all the id's of the url coming from database

Comment: you want to change the table's urls according to the id parameter of the main url?

Comment: so then the approch is this

Comment: you can get the id as mentioned in my answer. Then you can call database query by that id. Then you can get the links from the database according to the main url's id paramater. Hope you got this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the id with `preg_replace` in string then you can do like below:

```
<?php
$string = 'http://anyurl/index.php?id=4876&abc=any';
$new_string = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', $_GET["id"], $string);
echo $new_string;
// Will display http://anyurl/index.php?id=3345&abc=any 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that it was asked years ago, but, probably, someone will find my solution helpful

So, I also offer to use `preg_replace()`, as [Amit Gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47900713/14712811), but improve it for cases when you could have other numbers before ID value:

```php
$url     = 'http://anyurl/index.php?foo=0713&id=4876&abc=any';
$new_id  = $_GET['id'];
// regex: catch 1 or more digits after 'id='
$new_url = preg_replace( '/id=(\d+)/', $new_id, $url );
```

If `$_GET['id']` is `4920`, for example, `$new_url` will be equal to `http://anyurl/index.php?foo=0713&id=4920&abc=any`